# Does when comparison ignores case of String?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a method which takes String as input and returns an Integer corresponding to it as shown below :

```
    fun getPriority(groupValue: String?): Int {
        when (groupValue) {
            "one" -> return 10
            "Two" -> return 9
            "THREE" -> return 8
            else -> return 4
        }
    }
```

My Question is String comparison in this case takes case of string into consideration or ignores case?

Comment: Can you explain what ׳case of string’ means

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself ? you already have the code written .

Comment: It means if String is "one" than return 10 for it. I use it in a comparator.

Comment: String comparison works with the `equals` method. Two strings are equal if they have all the characters _the same_, not equivalent by case conversion.

Comment: @Tarun pls choose an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`when` does a `equals`-comparison, so it is case-sensitive indeed (see also [`String.equals`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/equals.html)).

Ignoring case sensitivity can be accomplished in several ways, one of which is already shown by Willi Mentzel... Some other (depending on what you want to accomplish):

```
fun getPriority(groupValue : String?) = when {
  groupValue == null -> /* handle the null first, so you can concentrate null-safe on the rest later */ 4
  groupValue.equals("one", ignoreCase = true) -> 10 /* ignoreCase = false is the default */
  /* ... */
  else -> 4
}
```

If it's that simple Willis approach will probably suffice you already.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is case sensitive, because `String.equals` is invoked as Roland already said.

**To make it case insensitive:**

```
fun getPriority(groupValue: String?) = when (groupValue?.toLowerCase()) {
    "one" -> 10
    "two" -> 9
    "three" -> 8
    else -> 4
}
```

Tip: since `when` is an expression, you can use the expression body notation for your function.

**Alternative:**

Use a `Map` instead of `when`. This becomes especially handy if your code should be dynamic.

```
val priorityMapping = mapOf(
    "one" to 10,
    "Two" to 9,
    "THREE" to 8
)

fun getPriority(groupValue: String?): Int { 

    groupValue?.let {
        priorityMapping.forEach { (key, value) -> 
            if(key.equals(it, true)) {
                return value
            }
        }   
    }

    return 4 // default value
}
```

Comment: That requires the checks to be lower-cased though. A true case-insensitive check would be done with `equals(other: String, caseInsensitive: Boolean)`, but it's not directly accessible without making a method call

Comment: @Zoe since we are dealing with string constants, that's no problem at all.

Comment: @Zoe I added a more dynamic alternative. Hope you like it :)

Answer (score 1):

As other answers has stated, the `when`-expression uses the `equals` method for comparison. The equals method on `String` is case sensitive by default.

If you want to compare objects on something else than its `equals` method, you could create a small wrapper class with it's own implementation of `equals`. This might be a little overkill in your particular case, but it might be useful in other cases.

The wrapper class:

```
// In Kotlin 1.3, this class could probably be inlined.
class CaseInsensitiveString(val s: String) {
    fun equals(other: Any) = 
        (other as? CaseInsensitiveString)?.s?.equals(s, ignoreCase = true) ?: false

    // Overriding hashCode() just so it's consistent with the equals method.
    override fun hashCode() = s.toLowerCase().hashCode()
}
```

A convenient extension property to wrap a `String`:

```
val String.caseInsensitive
    get() = CaseInsensitiveString(this)
```

Now you can do this:

```
fun getPriority(groupValue: String?): Int {
    when (groupValue?.caseInsensitive) {
        "one".caseInsensitive -> return 10
        "Two".caseInsensitive -> return 9
        "THREE".caseInsensitive -> return 8
        else -> return 4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already stated, `when` uses `equals` to form a boolean expression if a scalar (or a list of scalars) is placed in front of the `->` sign. Therefore (snippet from official [docs of when](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) - block comments are mine):

```
when (x) {
    1 -> print("x == 1") /* same as x.equals(1) or x == 1 */
    2 -> print("x == 2") /* same as x.equals(2) or x == 2 */
    else -> { // Note the block
        print("x is neither 1 nor 2")
    }
}
```

According to the [doc of `text.equals`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/equals.html):

> **Parameters**
>
> ignoreCase - true to ignore character case when comparing characters. **By default
>   fals**e.
>
> Two characters are considered the same ignoring case if at least one
>   of the following is true:
>
> - The two characters are the same (as compared by the == operator)
> - Applying the method toUpperCase to each character produces the same result
> - Applying the method toLowerCase to each character produces the same result

So in you case `groupValue.equals("one")` is the same as `groupValue.equals("one", ignoreCase = false)` therefore the answer is yes, when you use `when` on a `String` **by default the comparison will consider casing**.